# SetupComplete.cmd not working the same as when ran normally

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have a SetupComplete.cmd script i have that installs OpenVPN silently it inserts the certificate first for the TAP driver so it the install remains unattended.

this is the code i have:

```
CD /D %~dp0
ECHO PLEASE WAIT DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW...
@ECHO OFF
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" Tools\Silent\OpenVPN\OpenVPN.cer
CALL Tools\Silent\OpenVPN\OpenVPN-S.exe /S
```

This works perfect when ran normally and also when running from C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts
However when ran after first install it gives an error and says that system cannot find the .cer file.

I have also tried to set the certificate as a variable and that did exactly the same thing.
Does anybody know why this occurs and how to fix it ?

Comment: Does C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\Tools\Silent\OpenVPN\OpenVPN.cer exist?

Comment: Two pieces of advice, change `CD /D %~dp0` to `CD /D "%~dp0\Tools\Silent"`, _(shortening your two paths respectively)_, and either change `CALL` to `Start ""`, or depending upon what comes next in your script, remove `CALL` completely.

Comment: Yep it exists. and thanks for the tip i use call because i need the script to wait untill install is finished then install the next software automatically, why do you advise to remove it ?

Comment: The Windows setup process runs your script as System. Does system have the needed access rights to the folders and files in the Tools directory?

Comment: Please cut and paste the full output from your script into your post.

Comment: well at the start of script it asks for admin then runs cmd window as admin so yes it has correct access. this is the output:
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: ive tried again so many different things since this post but its always the same. It works fine when ran from pc even from Windows\Setup\Scripts folder but if try in a VM when installing windows it doesn't work. I have checked and the .cer is copied to the relevant folders perfectly. I just dont get it